# C4_4 Reflection!

Tags: code-golf, string, ascii-art

In this challenge, your task is to input a rectangle ASCII pattern (You may assume only printable characters need to be handled, and you may assume a trailing newline or not), C4_4 symmetrify, and output it.

Here, C4_4 symmetric means symmetric under 90-degree rotation around a corner of the corner character. The corresponding "symmetrify" process is copy and rotate 90-degree clockwise three times, and then put all four copies together. For the precise arrangement, you can look at Test Cases.

## Test Cases

```
Input:
asdf
jkl;

Output:
    ja
    ks
asdfld
jkl;;f
  f;;lkj
  dlfdsa
  sk
  aj


Input:
.O.
..O
OOO

Output:
.O.O..
..OO.O
OOOOO.
.OOOOO
O.OO..
..O.O.


Input:
gc
oo
ld
fe

Output:
  gc    
  oo    
  ldflog
  feedoc
codeef  
golfdl  
    oo  
    cg
```

Comment: I'd suggest to add a test case where the height of the input is strictly greater than its width.

Comment: Hmm... emoticons? 4_4

Answer (score 7):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 6 bytes

```
Ａ⟲Ｃ²⁴⁶
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMMzr6C0RENT05orKL8ksSTVOb@gUsPIxEzT@v//aCUlpcTilDSurOwcayA79r9uWQ4A) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: `Ａ` implicitly prints the input, `⟲` performs the rotation, `Ｃ` signifies to keep copies, and `²⁴⁶` represents the numbers of 45-degree rotations to make. (Charcoal defaults to rotating around the bottom-right corner as desired.)

Comment: Yet another fastest gun! Yeah, Charcoal is very suitable for this challenge. Have a +1!

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 193 bytes

```python
def f(s):q=len(s[0])-len(s);s=[[" "]*len(s[0])]*q+s;s=[[" "]*-q+l for l in s];j=lambda a,b:[x+y for x,y in zip(a,b)];r=lambda x:[*map(list,zip(*x[::-1]))];return j(s,r(s))+j(r(r(r(s))),r(r(s)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY5LboQwEETX8SlarNz8lCg7I05ieeERoJgY27g9EszliWE0SdSbUr@qUoU9fXn3eRzDOMHECcXa29Fxku8Km0thR72UBRSq/CWqXCv6@zdrZWHyESwYB6S6ubd6uQ0adH0Tcqv2i271fvKHCTz/UXXxZduELBcduDWU6pOXmxSi@VB4usZ0jw5mTnXMc7Caebwua6xf4jBL8DEB7cSYcQF6kGdd7nQjPtdldQ3cqaU0GNfGUQ8cWwrWpJMSR8WYv6ecnnhuQcb@JzMR7C1E4xIvinb2xj378dA0TGz@tt0P)

Comment: I was not expecting this to happen. Nice work!

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 38 bytes

```
(,|."1@|.)@(,.|:@|.)@((2$_1*>./)@${.])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/NXRq9JQMHWr0NB00dPRqrCAsDSOVeEMtOz19TQeVar1Yzf@aXApcqckZ@QppCkYKJgoqCuqJxSlpWdk51uoQcXV1mLwxEALl9Qz09PT8gQBDgYmCIUhBcn5Kqvp/AA)

No doubt it can be golfed much further.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>178</s>  173 bytes

Takes input as an array of strings. Returns a string.

```javascript
m=>(g=x=>~y?(Y=y<w?y:W-y,X=x<w?x:W-x,Z=y<w^x<w?Y:X,(m[Z-z*d]||0)[(X^Y^Z)+!z*d]||' ')+[`
`[x-W]]+g(x<W?x+1:!y--):'')(0,w=m[0].length,h=m.length,d=w-h,(z=d>0)?0:w=h,y=W=w*2-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dcvJboMwFIXhPU/hrGzHg0iXNBcewUsGCxQUpiYMUYmKHUV9dRqCKnXR7L579N9T/pWPx8@Py1X0Q1HOFcwd@KQGA/63DUgMdj8F1guF5RGYh83DhifLni137EWcdDoRt22R3u8u1STK4iyhbLMuGGHK9ME5aCPCNGU1MfswMGznbawQ1MOYEpdP0Gk3lW3Z19eGN9D9soBJNJzcoPBdGrjeBA23EMK0fRM7Oh@HfhzaUrZDTSqiHYRwPhYV5otO5/YdOymljvNPJ5VcMynVCqXU6xwptFYI/cmfEMw8/@Yf)

Answer (score 2):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 217 bytes

```
func[a][n: max(l: length? a)length? a/1
p: copy""insert/dup p" "n
loop n - l[insert a copy p]forall a[pad/left a/1 n]repeat y n[repeat x n[append
a/:y a/(n - x + 1)/:y]]repeat y n[append a reverse copy a/(n - y + 1)]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY6xbsMwDER3fcVBU4KiMLK6Q/@hq6CBsKg4LSsRshLYX@8qsVG0QIcOBA7kuzsWDusbB@dN7Nd4TYMj71KPT5oP0kM4nev4Cjp@q@5ktMeQdbH2kiYutQtXhVrYZCRnRcIzxG030AOF@pgLiYCcUuiEY71HIfnCylSxILldzk2SKqdgqOuXxh3ukTOecDq2hf/p2cBWU/jGZeKtbrcsD4v3aytnGkYURDhLU4jt3fcPebEeTsslVRSPTUg0v/EhBz5nif9hx5bLbWSf/Kdp/QI)

Returns a list of strings

Comment: pad, append, reverse! This is plain English. I like it.

Comment: @TwilightSparkle Thanks! I like it too :)

Comment: I'm curious why Red uses `[]` unlike lisp.

Comment: @TwilightSparkle I don't know.. [] is a block (list), () is used for grouping

Comment: Is this block the same kind of "block" in GolfScript?

Comment: @TwilightSparkle I don't know GolfScript. In Red blocks are doubly-linked lists that can consist of everything.

Comment: And can be executed?

Comment: Yes. Unlike LISP the blocks are quoted and need to be `reduce`d in order each `word` (symbol) be evaluated, or executed with `do`. [A short How Red works explanation](https://github.com/red/red/wiki/%5BNOTES%5D-How-Red-Works---A-brief-explanation)

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I think I will probably get deeper into this language, maybe.

Answer (score 1):

## [Icon](https://github.com/gtownsend/icon), <s>255</s> 206 bytes

```
procedure f(a)
n:=*a;n<:=t:=*a[1]
1to n-*a&push(a,repl(" ",t))&\z
(!a)[1:1]:=repl(" ",n-t)&\z
i:=1to n&j:=1to n&a[i]||:=a[n-j+1,i]&\z
i:=1to n&put(a,"")&j:=1to 2*n&a[n+i]||:=a[n-i+1,2*n-j+1]&\z
return a
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY9NbsMgEIX3nILMwgIHL@gSl5NQFsgeN7gOWAQnapW7p9hK@rOo1JGeNJr3Ps2M72K43eYUO@yXhHRgjpOgdO3a8Kx0XjsjLZE50tDUrpqX04E5kXCeGFAQmfPq5YOwneNGKmmV/rJCkzfPK73h1fhonPH2elXamdCMeym8/ZWbl1xWAPAH8VSvTNh/U75QZbrSG5swLylQRzD0P945Oh8YJ7QUnjG900vyGdluYAbcqR9AUBjfphYs5@3d/CPexR5f4zT8I3oAAVg03RVXZrvsEw)

Comment: No Red answer? :P

Comment: @TwilightSparkle Maybe I'll write one :)

Comment: I'm waiting for it then LOL

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 140 bytes

```python
def f(a):l=len(a[0]);k=len(a)-l;b=[k*' '+i for i in-k*[l*' ']+a];b+=[*map(''.join,zip(*b))][::-1];return[i+j[::-1]for i,j in zip(b,b[::-1])]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY49bsQgEEZ7n4IOxj8oUTojn4EDIAqITYJNALFO4b28d8FJETLVzON9n4jH/hn823nOi0GGKBjd5BZPlHiRwLZrh8ExPYmtxQh3FpmQkEXWD1srXGayU5LpbhLtl4oEY7oG6/u7jaTVAFKM4/AqWVr27@SF7dYLlJp@fRahrOpeXxxk@cxsb9Gpg6iU1AFjg56TI876JWcKH1FM1u8kQyjKdUPT/OYNEVjdZoP78v4zeN0cwxLgj/fxXlkhVMDNFTDLvxbKaSVRyivCOc@58wE)

Expects and returns a list of lines.

#### Explanation

```python
def f(a):
 l=len(a[0]);k=len(a)-l;                     # Extract dimensions
 b=[k*' '+i for i in-k*[l*' ']+a];           # Make it square
 b+=[*map(''.join,zip(*b))][::-1];           # Construct left half of the output
 return[i+j[::-1]for i,j in zip(b,b[::-1])]  # Construct the right half and return
```

Comment: A nice approach!

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 22 bytes

```apl
{(⌽⍪⊖)(⍉,⌽)⍵↑⍨-2/⌈/⍴⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v1rjUc/eR72rHnVN09R41NupA@RqPurd@qht4qPeFbpG@o96OvQf9W4BCtX@T3vUNuFRb9@jruZHvWuAgofWG4PU9U0NDnIGkiEensH/0xSAQuoeqTk5@eoK6uH5RTkp6gA)